# MP3 players playback speed

Tags: playback, mp3-player

I am looking for an MP3 player where I can increase playback speed so I can listen to classes faster. I've called stores and searched online, but can't seem to find anything. What MP3 players have variable speed playback?

Comment: If this is a MP3-player hardware recommendation request, I think that would be off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adjust the speed in almost every player. For example in VLC it should be possible by the keys [ and ] . I checked that for Rhytmbox there is also a plugin called RBPitch in case you decide not to install other applications. But I would choose VLC - it supports it natively and has broad application so it is good to have it anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I mean a portable MP3 player, not on the computer.